# What is the antonym of "assemble a team"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, programming

in the context of the computer software industry, what would be the opposite of "assemble a team"?

a colleague of mine (who is a native english speaker) suggested "dissemble", but looking up the [word meaning](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dissemble) yield:

> **Dissemble**
>
> Conceal or disguise one's true feelings or beliefs […]

… so it seems she meant "[**disassemble**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disassemble)":

> **Disassemble**
>
> Take (something) to pieces […]

since i don't question her lingual skills, i wonder; could "**dissemble**" be used in that context, interchangeably?

Comment: @EliranMalka did your coworker suggest *dissemble* verbally or in writing? many speakers will slur or skip the extra syllable in *disassemble*, making the two words sound identical

Comment: To be clear: "dissemble" could not possibly be used, in its existing dictionary definition, to be the opposite of "assemble". But it's likely a common mistake.

Comment: From experience, the opposite of "assembling a development team" is "designing a project".

Comment: to put this question in context, [here's the goal of my research on disassembling teams](https://github.com/eliranmal/git-flux/blob/master/git-flux-team#L96-L98) (API design on an open source software project) :)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

MorganFR wrote in a comment: "you're probably looking for *disband* or one of its synonyms."

***Disband*** — [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disband)

> transitive verb:  to break up the organization of :  dissolve
> intransitive verb:  to break up as an organization :  disperse
>
> *"They've decided to disband the club."*
> *"The members of the organization have decided to disband."*

Comment: what about my secondary question; could "dissemble" be used in place of "disassemble"?

Comment: @EliranMalka I'd say *yes* unless you're writing formally, in which case *maybe* (depending on if it's strictly correct, which it may not be). If you say "he dissembled the team" in a conversation, *everyone* will understand exactly what you mean

Comment: dissemble means to lie. disassemble means to break apart.

Comment: @Joe - i'm glad to hear that, since i was looking for the shortest word that conveys the meaning, and the term will be used in the most informal context, i.e. it will be the name of a command in a command-line tool, used by developers (we're as casual as can be..)

Comment: @PaulChernoch - thank you, that was established already, i was looking for a loophole :)

Comment: @EliranMalka I would say that using *dissemble* when you mean *take apart* is an error.  People might still do it, as your colleague suggested, but they would be wrong.

Comment: Thirding @PaulChernoch. You *can* use dissemble when you mean *disband* or *disassemble*, but you run the risk that someone who hears you/reads your code will actually know what the word means and either a) get confused about what you mean or b) know what you mean, but think you sound ignorant.

Comment: @1006a - good point; i certainly do not wanna sound ignorant. you win.

Comment: @1006a "_You can use dissemble_"... You might as well say that you _can_ use _**aardvark**_ when you mean disband or disassemble, but you run the risk that someone [...] gets confused (unless you're [Humpty Dumpty](https://www.fecundity.com/pmagnus/humpty.html)).  OP should stick with _disband_.

Comment: @TripeHound Yes, that was my point...which the OP got.

Comment: _If you say "he dissembled the team" in a conversation, everyone will understand exactly what you mean._  I think this is true, but not because 'dissembled' makes sense here.  In fact, precisely because it does _not_ make sense, everyone will automatically assume that you meant "he disassembled the team" but slurred/elided/muted the 'a' sound. Most people wouldn't even consciously notice the difference between what you said and what they understood.

Comment: @Timbo Until you said this, there is a good chance I would NOT have understood what someone meant by *"he dissembled the team"*. I tend to take things very literally and precisely without meaning to, and I have a large vocabulary. I stumble at the difference in pronunciation between "effect" and "affect", "your" and "you're", and so on. I once thought Beccy wasn't at a social function because I heard the questioner ask for "Becky".

Answer (score 47):

**dissolve**.

See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissolve

Typical uses are to: dissolve parliament, dissolve a partnership, dissolve a marriage. "break up" is given as its synonym.

Part of the definition from Merriam-Webster:

> transitive verb
>
> 1a :  to cause to disperse or disappear :  destroy (do not dissolve
>   and deface the laws of charity — Francis Bacon)
>
> 1b :  to separate into component parts :  disintegrate (dissolved the
>   company into smaller units)
>
> 1c :  to bring to an end :  terminate (the king's power to dissolve
>   parliament) (their partnership was dissolved)
>
> 1d law :  annul (dissolve an injunction)

Comment: While it's good that you provided a link to a definition, you should ***also*** quote the relevant parts of the definition.

Answer (score 28):

[**Break up**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/break_up)

> 1.1 (of a gathering or collective) disband

In your context, you might say

> After Tim left, management decided to break up the team

Also consider 'split':

> After Tim left, management decided to split the team

Comment: Just an observation of different nuances.  Disband implies the the team ceases to exist.  Split implies that the team is divided and the pieces continue to exist.  Break up is ambiguous.  It could mean the same as disband.  It could mean the same as split.  It could also refer to "repurposing" the team members in a way that preserves the team's experience by seeding the members into other teams.

Comment: @fixer1234 Definitely true. Good point.

Answer (score 9):

In the peculiar project management parlance the [stages of team development](https://project-management.com/the-five-stages-of-project-team-development/) are:

> The five stages:
>
> Stage 1: Forming
>
> Stage 2: Storming
>
> Stage 3: Norming
>
> Stage 4: Performing
>
> Stage 5: Adjourning

You are asking about the final stage, [adjourning](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/adjourning), as the project is closed out and the team disbands.

Comment: it rhymes! love it! </authentic>

Comment: True or not, I wouldn't recognise any of these terms.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree they are not normal English, however they are common terms in software project management, which is the area the OP mentioned.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Sorry, I forgot I'm not on Stack Overflow here so you wouldn't know — to be clear, I'm a software development manager. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In that case I probably should specify that they're PMI terminology straight out of PMBOK. None of which is necessary to actually competently manage a project, of course,  but credentialism rules these days.

Comment: Feels like "adjourning" was chosen bacause it rhymes, not because it it the most appropriate...

Comment: @heltonbiker Only, it doesn't rhyme! Unless you pronounce it incorrectly. "Form" doesn't sound like "fern".

Comment: @heltonbiker Agreed -  'Adjourning' implies that it's only a temporary halt, whereas the implication of 'final stage' is that it's permanent.

Comment: @peterG Of course in an organization that is project-oriented, members of the team will likely be reassigned to work together on other projects so it's not completely outlandish.

Answer (score 3):

I think that there are nuances to the chosen antonym. *Dissolve* and *disband* imply that the team is disassembled virtually passively - the individuals returning to previous roles. *Dismantling* the team conveys a requirement for additional effort, perhaps to identify alternative placements for the defunct team's members.

*Dissolve* is frequently used to describe a process that requires little or no apparent effort:

"*Casein (a dairy protein) will not simply dissolve in water*."
"*After failing to convene for the third time in succession, the Office Party Committee dissolved by unspoken consent.*"

*Disband* is generally used when members of a group or unit stop acting collectively:

"*I started the band, I disbanded it. It's as simple as that.*" - John Lennon.

*Dismantle* requires work to be done and does not generally occur effortlessly:

Originally meant to describe the destruction of the defenses of a fortress (French: "uncloaking" the fortress), the word still conveys that effort is required.

"*The Lego Certified Professional will carefully dismantle his prototype, rather than dropping it on the workbench to break it apart*"

Comment: Can you provide some sources to back up your response? Where is the information re: the inherent implications contained within _dismantling_, _dissolve_ and _disband_ coming from?

Comment: @freeling10 Done.

Answer (score 2):

What about **Dismantle**?

> **definition**: to get rid of a system or organization, usually over a period of time:
>
> -*Over the next three years, we will be gradually dismantling the company and selling off the profitable units.*
>
> -*Unions accuse the government of dismantling the National Health Service.*

Source: *Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus* © Cambridge University Press

Comment: Note that "dismantle" has a connotation: That of destroying from the outside, hollowing-out? So it's used in distructive/negative contexts.

Answer (score 2):

"Dissemble" only ever means fibbing, lying or obfuscating. Is is not an antonym of "assemble". Probably grammarians have a term for this, "false antonym" or something.

As others have said, "disband" or "dissolve" would be the normal words to use for breaking up a team. "Disassemble" is an antonym for assemble but is not, in my experience, idiomatic for disbanding a group of people in formal contexts.

Your friend may be engaging in word play (I had a friend who insisted on "disintegrate" for taking the derivative in calculus, since it was the opposite of integrating) or she may be making an honest mistake. "Dissemble" is actually pretty obscure and it's possible she heard it in an ambiguous context and just starting using it for what it *sounds* like it might mean. "Infamous" is another one that that happens to. Perhaps someone famous will use "dissemble the committee" on Twitter and it'll catch on.

Comment: I suppose "disintegrate" *would* have been the term had the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus come before the two separate branches.

Answer (score -1):

It's verb (noun is different) **break up**
phrasal verb of break

> **definition:** 
>   disintegrate or disperse. "the grey clouds had begun to break up" (of
>   a gathering or collective) disband; end. "after about an hour, the
>   meeting broke up"

*Michael was first, but still.*

Comment: your answer is somewhat incomprehensible, what word are you suggesting to use?

Comment: Break up, I edited the answer.